# WP All Import image edit

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I have a XML that has two elements names `<picture>` and `<url>`, I am using WP All Import to get the picture element download the picture at the same time I want the element to hyperlink the picture element.

My code:

```
function my_custom_func() {
    $url=@url[1];
    $image=@picture[1];
echo '<a href=$url> <img url=picture[1] /> </a>';
}
```

but with no success, any help!

the xml

```
<element1>
  <picture>
    http://pictureurl.image/image.jpg
  </picture>
  <url>
    http://url.image/image.jpg
  </url>
</element1>
```

Answer (score 0):

How i would to it:

```
function my_custom_func($url, $image) {
return <a href = $url> <img url = $image>;
}
```

Add this in the field you want it in

```
[my_custom_func({url[1]}, {picture[1]})]
```